# One tablix, two formats

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have an invoice document that (depending whether the document in question is for a foreign customer) will print the local amount as a column in the tablix contents.

I could just hide the "Local Amount" column if I detect it's a local invoice, but that will mean that I still need to take that column into account when designing the header. If the "Local Amount" column doesn't print, the header will look lopsided as I will spread it across the page based on the tablix with "Local Amount"

Is there a way to extend one of the column's length if one of the other columns don't print? For example, if the "Local Amount" column doesn't print, I want the "Item" column to extend and take up the slack.

I could just use two tablix and hide/show one or the other based on conditions, but I'm hoping for another method.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a formula to adjust the width of the Header? So if you hide "Local Amount" then have an equation in the header checks the same parameter and adjust the header width.